# Search pagination rewrite to fix 404

Tags: pagination, search, rewrite-rules

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out here?

Basically, I think I need to use `add_rewrite_rule()` to get pagination working in my **search results**, as I've gone beyond the default query due to a bunch of extra stuff that needs to happen when fetching results (querying posts and users, in this case).

The first page of my search results works fine.

Example: `/?s=lighting&post_type=service`.

However, when I go to the second page of results, I get a 404.

Example: `/?s=lighting&post_type=service&paged=2`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Here's a condensed version of my query and any relevant code:

```
// Working with the query string
global $query_string;
$user_query_args = explode('&', $query_string );
$user_query_array = array();
if ( strlen( $query_string ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $user_query_args as $key => $string ) {
        $user_query_split = explode( '=', $string );
        $user_query_array[$user_query_split[0]] = urldecode( $user_query_split[1] );
    }
}

// Setting up `$paged`
global $paged;
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
if ( $paged === 1 ) {
    $offset = 0;
} else {
    $offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $per_page;
}

// Args for user query
$user_args = array(
    'number' => $per_page,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'role' => 'Subscriber',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'profile_service_1',
            'value' => $posts_str, // string of post IDs
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'profile_service_2',
            'value' => $posts_str, // string of post IDs
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    )
);

// Creating the user query
$users_query = new WP_User_Query( array_merge( $user_query_array, $user_args ) );
$users = $users_query->get_results();

if ( sizeof( $users ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        // Here's where I show the user stuff
    }
}

// Setting up pagination
$total_users = $users_query->total_users;
$total_pages = ceil( $total_users / $per_page );

$pagination_args = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => $paged,
    'total' => $total_pages,
    'prev_text' => 'Previous',
    'next_text' => 'Next',
    'type'     => 'list',
);

if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) {
    $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ).'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
}

if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) ) {
    $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
}

echo paginate_links( $pagination_args );
```

Comment: that's because you're asking WP for page 2 of the main post query, not your new secondary additional query. Have you considered using `pre_get_posts` instead? Rewrite rules will not fix this if raw URL parameters can't

Comment: Yep, I did play around with `pre_get_posts` with a check for the search query, but I didn't have much luck on that front.

Comment: without knowing what you tried, or seeing the code for your attempt or the query you've written on the search page it's not possible to advise, but this is expected when you use that particular method, it's just rare that people notice

Comment: Yeah fair enough. I was initially just looking for pointers, hence me not adding the query etc. However, I've just updated my question with all relevant code, if that helps you to understand what's happening. Thanks

Comment: ***You did not mention it's a `WP_User_Query` not a post query***, that was super important and critical to know. In this situation you should not have used the `s` parameter as that is for post queries, you should not be repurposing the `search.php` template either. I also spotted that you used the `@` operator which is extremely bad, `@` does not swallow errors, it only silences error messages, _the error still happens!_ Only now they don't appear in error logs so it's ultra difficult to debug fatal errors, it would be easier and safer to fix the problem `@` is trying to hide

Comment: Uh, I did mention "querying posts and users", so figured it'd be clear that I was using `WP_User_Query`, but my apologies for getting your back up about that one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: not backed up at all! It's bolded so that it's clear for other users who may miss that, and to emphasise as it's pivotal piece of info to answering the question, querying posts and users could just mean author archives or a sidebar. Not knowing it leads towards answers oriented around `pre_get_posts` which would be of no help to you. I've left an answer, If it solves your problem consider marking it as the correct answer, otherwise if it does not leave a comment on it so that I can improve it and other users can avoid the same mistakes when writing their own answers

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you're using `s`, the post query search parameter, *but the code is for a user query*.

This means if your user query has 5 pages, but only 2 pages of posts are found, page 3 will 404.

Instead, use a dedicated parameter with `$_GET` that isn't a reserved query var already. This does mean the `search.php` template won't be used, but that can be fixed in many ways, e.g. a page template, rewrite rules, template filters, etc

---

#### A sidenote on performance

`meta_query` has very poor performance. If the values you are searching for are not fuzzy, consider using user taxonomies to store them. This will provide a dramatic performance boost. Post/User/Term meta are optimised for `get_post_meta` type calls where you already know the post ID, the tables are not structured in a way that makes searches/filtering/grouping posts by meta performant.

Keep this in mind as there is a tradeoff here, meta is fast in `get_post_meta` type situations, and gets significantly slower at `meta_query` type situations as the table increases in size. Taxonomies aren't as fast for retrieval but they're orders of magnitude faster than `meta_query` type queries. This is why categories and tags aren't stored in post meta, but stuff like the featured image ID are.